# how to create hostnames using while loop in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

is there any way to do the while loop to create the EC2 instances that will create for example 20 instances and add the hostnames in each instance and its private IP and updating `/etc/resolv.conf`.

So for example it will create instance = host1, for that EC2 instance it will setup the hostname = host1 add the entry in `/etc/hosts` with `host1` and its IP = `10.0.1.1`, for `host2` it will setup the instance = host2 with entities in /etc/hosts : host2 and its IP = `10.0.1.2` and so on.

It can be done in shell script, but how it can be done in ansible ?

Thanks.
Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with_sequence`. For the details see the docs at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/sequence.html

You'll probably do something like this:

```
- name: Creating hosts
  debug: msg="hostname: host{{ item }} ip: 10.0.1.{{ item }}"
  with_sequence: start=1 end=20
```